# How to toggle MySQL result grid indexing

Tags: mysql-workbench

This is more of a viewing preference of MySQL workbench issue. My result grid does not have the # indexing at the Result Grid. My classmate has it, but claimed it shows automatically after downloading MySQL.

Mine shows as this:

[pic without index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emsdh.png)

**Result Grid**

_|Column|Column

*|value*|value_

*|value*|value_

My mates' show as this automatically without altering the table

[pic with index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0PC7.png)

**Result Grid**

#|Column|Column

1|value_|value_

2|value_|value

I tried searching through the settings, but nothing. It is not a big deal, but it's something nice to have.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may find a difference in the table definitions.